# MD-Raid Superblock gets deleted

Tags: raid, mdadm

I'm having a linux machine with a regular RAID-1 on 2 HDD's.
Everything seems fine, but about one time per day it seems to wipe the superblock.
If i run `mdadm --create --assume-clean --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/md0 /dev/sda /dev/sdb` everything seems fine though. `mdadm --assemble` says that it can't find a valid superblock (on both drives).
I don't know if it matters but i made a Hexdump from before and after RAID recreation: (`head /dev/sda | hexdump -C`)

[image]
It's not only at reboot, it also happens while the PC is running.
Do you have any ideas what it could be?

dumpe2fs shows the following for **both** sda and sdb:

```
dumpe2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Maybe the error is because i made the RAID on the whole disk and not just on the partition?

Comment: Why did you use **tail**? The primary superblock resides in the block **0** hence the name(although there are multiple backups in different locations).What is the output of the command ```dumpe2fs /dev/sda | grep -i superblock``` and the same for ```/dev/sdb``` ?

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I'm sorry, i meant **head** - corrected it. I added the dumpe2fs output.

Comment: Yes , the problem possibly is because of the partitioning problem.Different disks even with the exact same advertized capacity might have a different size.And it can cause problems when you create RAID on them.It's already answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320103/whats-the-difference-between-creating-mdadm-array-using-partitions-or-the-whole).

Comment: Create two partitions with the exact same size on those two disks , then create your RAID again.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be the problem described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/484532
I just ran "sgdisk --zap" on both devices and added them again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be the Mainboard wiping the data, because there was still a part of the GPT formatting left.
Details are explained here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/484532
Running `sgdisk --zap /dev/sda` and `sgdisk --zap /dev/sdb` solved the issue.